# How to return a value by class name itself in C++?

Tags: c++, class, abstract-data-type

I'm working on a wrapper class for `char[]` in c++. Something like a `String`. Now I want to get a value from the object name. For example:

```
void main() {
    String str;
    str = "Hello";
    cout << str;
}
```

so the `str` return a `character array`, and `cout` can print it on the screen. How can I achieve this in my class? *(By the way, I know there is already a string class. This is an exercise for `Data Structures` lesson)*

Comment: Read about `operator<<` overload.

Comment: @Lasoloz You mean binary left shift operator overloading?

Comment: Yes! STL classes also use it.

Comment: @HosseinMaktoobian You can also overload the cast operator alternatively.

Comment: A good point to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx  . C++ rererence documentations are also good.

Comment: `main` should return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: In your example, you should also overload `=` operator.

Comment: @Lasoloz I did the = operator overload. I was trying to handle the stream. and as @SergeyA mentioned, I was looking in a wrong direction. thank you all. that was the `output stream` operator;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you mean:

```
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const String & s)
{
    return os << s.get_char_pointer();
}
```

Of course you will need to change `get_char_pointer` to whatever works for your `String`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking in the wrong direction. You do not need `str` to *return* a character array (which of course it can't anyway). While technically you can define a *conversion operator* on your `String` class, it is not recommended, since it can have an unintended effect.

Instead, **overload** `operator<<`, giving your class as it's second argument, and perform streaming there.